# How to check inheritance on parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am creating a class that implements `java.util.List`. My class is using `E` to represent the parameterized type.

I want to call `Collections.sort` to sort the internal list I'm wrapping with my class. The problem is that this requires my list to have types that implement comparable.

Like the sort method, I want to be able to take a comparator, so I don't want to force E to be a subclass of Comparable. So, in the constructor that doesn't take a comparator, I want to verify that E implements Comparable.

So, how do I do this, O mighty java wizards?

Comment: So you want to force `E` to implement `Comparable` when you don't provide a comparator, but not otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No good way to do this. Just closing and moving on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two different classes or two builder methods for the compiler to check this.

```
CollectionOfAny<E> {
     CollectionOfAny(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
     }

     public static <E> CollectionOfAny<E> create(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
         return new CollectionOfAny<E>(comparator);
     }

     public static <E extends Comparator<E>> CollectionOfAny<E> create() {
         return new CollectionOfAny<E>(NaturalComparator.INSTANCE);
     }
}

CollectionOfComparable<E extends Comparable<E>> extends CollectionOfAny<E> {
     public CollectionOfComparable() {
         super(NaturalComparator.INSTANCE);
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried going down that path, but the sort method was still cranky about the generics. I'm going down the path of always using a comparator and using my own that calls compareTo to use the natural order.

Comment: That's what this does in effect. re: `NaturalComparator.INSTANCE`

Comment: I couldn't find the class NaturalComparator. Is that new with Java 7, because I'm still on 6?

Comment: Its something you have to write ;)

Comment: Aha! :) That would explain it.

Comment: if you are lazy you can just use `Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.<E>reverseOrder())` as the comparator ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use to find the interfaces

```
YourObject.class.getInterfaces();

private E ob;
    public void testComp(){
    ob.getClass().getInterfaces(); //try using this to get the class first
    }
```

///////////

```
public class run<E> implements Comparable{
private E ob;

public run(E ob){
    this.ob = ob;
}
public run() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        run r = new run<run>(new run()); //add an instance of the parametised object
        r.testComp();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


public boolean testComp(){
System.out.println(ob.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].toString());
return ob.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].toString().equals("java.lang.Comparable");
}


}
```

This prints out "interface java.lang.Comparable".

The string comparison is a work-around as you can't use the instanceof, because the Comparable interface itself needs to be parameterized, but this does check if it is of the the comparable interface. Any edits welcome!

Comment: When I try E.class.getGenericInterfaces() I get the message: "Illegal class literal for the type parameter E"

Comment: I have a test working but it is pretty messy so will post it in a minute!

Comment: The method I posted needs some personalisation, and the best way would then be to compare the string name to "java.lang.Comparable"

Comment: OK, thanks for the hard work, but again, when I need this, I don't have an instance of E. Things would get easier if I did.

Comment: You need an instance of E, for example, I just used a dummy object in my constructor to create one, which then allows the checks to be ran, otherwise you get a nullpointer. Sorry but thats the best I can come up with! maybe I haven't full understood your question :)!

Comment: Assuming you know the constructor. I suppose I could delay construction until the add method. Hmmmmm....

Comment: hmmmmmm,I'm not sure I now know 100% what your doing, but you could consider invoking the constructor via reflection again. Which constructor are you talking about?

Comment: The constructor for my internal ArrayList. The add method should be the first one called so I could delay instantiation until the add method was called, at which time I'd probably have an instance of the object. Unless it was null, of course, then I'm in trouble. Also, I'd have to hack at each of the other methods like size() to make sure there was an instance first.

Comment: If intialiaztion is complex as it is, i would consider then using a factory pattern as this can't be done nicely with one class. Take a look at http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: "as you can't use the instanceof, because the Comparable interface itself needs to be parameterized" What? Doesn't make any sense. `ob instanceof Comparable` works. It is not parameterized (cannot be, it is a runtime check), and neither does your current code check that. I see no difference

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory method. Factory methods are superior to constructors in pretty much every way. One may later return a more specific type, type inference works just fine without Java 7 and the diamond operator and... you can require different type parameter bounds for different factory methods:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> YourList<E> wrap(List<E> wrapped) {
  return new YourList<E>(wrapped);
}
```

Comment: For a second there i thought Peter had beat me to it.. but his solution is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator, `object instanceof Comparable` will return true if E implements Comparable.

Comment: I don't have an instance of the object at construction so instanceof doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
class MyList<E extends Comparable> implements List<E> {
...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Then this is the idea -- have factory with two static methods: first produces your list for `Comparable` implementators and second method produces your list for non-`Comparable`'s.

Here's sample code:

```
public class MyListFactory {
    static class OthersComparator implements Comparable{
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class MyList<E> {
        private final OthersComparator comparator;

        private final List<E> impl;

        private MyList() {
            this(null);
        }

        private MyList(OthersComparator comparator) {
            this.comparator = comparator;
            impl = new ArrayList<E>();
        }

        public void sort() {
            if (comparator == null) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

    static <E extends Comparable> MyList<E> getForComparable(Class<E> aClass) {
        System.out.println("for comparables");
        return new MyList<E>();
    }

    static <E> MyList<E> getForOthers(Class<E> aClass) {
        System.out.println("for non-comparables");
        return new MyList<E>(new OthersComparator());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyListFactory.MyList<Object> l = MyListFactory.getForOthers(Object.class);
        MyListFactory.MyList<Integer> l2 = MyListFactory.getForComparable(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I indicated in the question, I don't want clients to have to implement Comparable if they provide a comparator.